# Mock SQS Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, mule, amazon-sqs, munit

I've created a mule application with the following configuration to SQS. This lives in my `config.xml` file.

```
<sqs:config name="amazonSQSConfiguration" accessKey="${aws.sqs.accessKey}" secretKey="${aws.sqs.secretKey}" url="${aws.sqs.baseUrl}" region="${aws.account.region}" protocol="${aws.sqs.protocol}" doc:name="Amazon SQS: Configuration">
    <reconnect count="5" frequency="1000"/>
</sqs:config>
```

This is problematic for me because when this SQS configuration loads up, it tries to connect to Amazon SQS queue but can't because access to the queue is not accessible from my machine.

For munit, unit purposes, I'm looking for a way to stop this from trying to connect on load?

Is there a way I can mock this `sqs:config`?

Please note this is different from mocking the connector in my flow? In this case I need to mock the config.

Or happy for any other suggestions.

thanks

Comment: Does your baseUrl contain the name of the queue?

Comment: At te time i posted this it didn't, but now it does

Comment: So after appending the name of a queue to your baseUrl, did the issue get resolved?

Comment: Have you got a solution for it?

Comment: I asked Mule and there is no way to stop sqs trying to connect

Comment: @Richie would you mind sharing that support ticket from mule if it's on a public forum?